# how to keep 2 copies of project files, one in svn and another for you?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I use eclipse and svn 1.6

What I basically want is to be able to switch between svn files and current I work with, so that
I could rollback to the state that I had before synchronizing and updating some files with svn changes.

I do not want to put local changes to svn. But I want the state of all files to be saved somewhere,
by using a magic command: "save project current state".

And so later I can return to that state. But I do not want to use svn for this purpose.
Svn is shared with other developers and is for stable release.
What I need is to be able to keep milestone states, and specifically NOT USE SVN for this purpose.

It's like copying all the files to a backup folder and later, when you need, copying all those files back.

Any plugins recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) for this, it can use svn as remote repository, and have all this stuff you asks (and much more).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'd actually recommend the usage of a branch if you want multiple variations on your code. That way you can also cross merge code as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The use of branches is exactly for such kind of usage. You can create an experimental branch and put your code there. If you're read just merge that branch back to the development line.

Comment: @khmarbaise will branch be saved on remote server?